# closing questions with an incorrect premise

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

As a dupehammer wielder, I have to be more careful about dupes now... So, here's a question where the premise is broken

[Encryption & Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570286/encryption-decryption-c-sharp)

The correct solution to the op's problem is not what the user is trying to do, and their XY approach has led them to ask the wrong question.

Do I close as a duplicate? To me the well upvoted answers represent misinformation in the context of the actual problem trying to be solved.

Comment: I don't think you should close as a duplicate if it's really isn't. You have done well providing a comment - that's what they are for but to resolve current OP's problem the solutions are given in the answers. I have had similar cases in VBA and Excel when a users asks for a macro to count something but another quesiton/answer achieves the same thing using a formula - just leave it open as someone else may come across this question and then they will see your upvoted comment.

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't a duplicate, then don't close it as one. There are lots and lots of *similar* questions with *similar* answers that are still not duplicates...

That said, don't let this stop you from leaning heavily on an existing answer posted to a related question. If you can get away with a short introduction relating the asker's problem to the answer that you then [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), go for it - cross-linking is good!